# New design: "X votes" should be "X score"

Tags: bug, design, voting, user-interface

Apparently, we have a new design for the question list. The left block, containing a summary of the question's "statistics", looks like this:

> [image]

That line that says *"38 votes"* is semantically incorrect as that question actually *received* 46 votes:

> [image]

(Assuming you only count up/downvotes, depending on how pedantic you want to be.)

That score counter should probably be labeled differently.

Comment: This is [already reported on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375181). But honestly there are far worse problems, like the fact that post score are now very de-emphasised and in smaller text. The whole point of posts having scores is to make useful posts easier to find...

Comment: Oh man, this is 12 days old already? Has there been something about this redesign on SO's meta?

Comment: *"There’s no point in acting surprised about it. All the planning charts and demolition orders have been on display at your local planning department in Alpha Centauri for 50 of your Earth years, so you’ve had plenty of time to lodge any formal complaint and it’s far too late to start making a fuss about it now."*

Comment: That is, I haven't seen anything written about it here, I think SE staff expect everyone to read meta.SE or not have an opinion. In the minutes since the change was rolled out, that post on meta.SE has received quite a few downvotes, for what it's worth.

Comment: I missed it completely until it just popped up (not regularly on Meta). I detest the new design.

Comment: @Cerbrus it was featured on MSE, and therefore visible from SO, for a week or so, but those don't appear on MSO

Comment: @KevinB Some of us are still shaking our heads over the fact that they separated MSE and MSO, because we knew stuff like this would happen.

Comment: They should revisit the whole... Featured on MSE not showing up on child metas bit, imo. It's not like we don't have space on the right column to add more junk.

Comment: Reminds me of a Product Manager saying. "Well we mentioned this over here so everyone should know it was going to be released", but the fact no user really has a reason to go there means no one sees it.

Comment: Yea I don't particularly keep an eye on main that much anymore. I agree that it not showing up on MSO is sub-optimal.

Comment: The real issue is that the stuff I am supposedly filtering for is no longer highlighted.

Comment: @kaya3 "So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish" StackExchange networks. It's uncomfortable to use after redesign.

Comment: I hear you. It's just... score is another evil, IMO. It's so gamey, like it is a competition. If the label "score" is introduced then points is soon to follow. My question has 30 points, my answer has -5 points. I kind of like votes more because at least it identifies what the number is about, even if it misrepresents the tallied number that is shown.

Comment: I agree, although this is the least of the problems

Comment: X net votes. :P

Comment: I think *up* votes were implied. That's how I took it anyway.

Comment: @code It's not upvotes, though, as that question got 42 of those.

Comment: @Cerbrus upvotes include compensation for downvotes when you visit a SE site without clicking on the vote count. It seems perfectly fine to me...