# Top Questions re-design in home page

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I just noticed the new design for **Top Questions** at **Home page**.

I feel that the previous design was much better. The new question statistic is too small and it's not easy to see all relevant question information quickly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New design: "X votes" should be "X score"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415527/new-design-x-votes-should-be-x-score)

Comment: There never were descriptions. https://web.archive.org/web/20220114014823/https://stackoverflow.com/?questions

Comment: Related: [Please revert the new question list style change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change)

Comment: These information should be in a column. We visually scroll our eyes top to bottom and when we have to read whether the number corresponds to a score or views or answers, it makes reading that list much more cumbersome.

Comment: I understand that by making the numbers smaller they made the titles bigger, but still this is a useless change that made things more worse than better.

Comment: @Dharman You are right. I don't know why I though that description was there. Probably because this new design has a lot of empty space, and on the first look on new design, it looked like something is missing.

Comment: it... has a lot of empty space, and is more cramped, at the same time.

Comment: If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it...

Comment: Please forgive them. They only have old mobile screens to test it on.

Comment: what are the bright (dark theme) Watched indicators and why are they on almost every question? is it really necessary to pull my eye to them that much?

Comment: The new top questions list looks horrible. It wastes screen real estate. Why on earth was this change made? "If it ain't broke -- DON'T FIX IT". Seriously this is not an improvement. Why wasn't this previewed before it was just dumped on the community? At least provide an option in "Settings" to go back to the old view. And, I checked -- It's not April 1st... Watched questions are not even highlighted anymore -- there is an unwanted yellow "Watched" box...

Comment: Every terrible redesign is a little push for another community-led Q&A site to take StackExchange's place.

Comment: There are only three certainties in life: death, taxes, and us giving Stack Exchange a hard time when they move our cheese.

Comment: Yeah, this is atrocious. It's a little bit worse than the old desktop view, and way way worse than the old mobile view.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I get very cranky when my cheese gets moved.

Comment: Folks, we need to avoid personal invective.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. When I go to https://stackoverflow.com it shows `Top Questions` which seems to be a selection of questions form topics I watch. As a result *every question* has this big `watched` badge (it's the most prominent feature). Why?…it's not really a useful tag if every question is tagged. Certainly not the most important thing.

Comment: Surprised to see so much negativity. Maybe it's just because I hardly ever go to that page but the new version looks great to me. It's really clean and easy to read.

Comment: @KevinB So many websites have this flaw nowadays. They redesign to add huge amounts of space, put less information on the page, and make it feel claustrophobic. I wonder if this trend has a name.

Comment: I only entered to meta to verify that I was not the only one who found the new design absolutely terrible, now I am calmer

Comment: I created a [custom user-style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375511/158281) (CSS only, not as intensive as a userscript) that attempts to bring the _Top Questions_ page back to the one we all know and love. It's working well for me so far in the Stylus browser extension

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is duplicated here: [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el?cb=1). I'd suggest you add your feedback there.

Comment: Is there any reason why it can't look exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions? Too easy? Too consistent?

Comment: when it comes to watched and ignored questions you know what it is ? black and yellow, black and yellow, black and yellow, black and yellow :P
Just joking, it will probably get some time to get used to

Comment: I agree, at least for the desktop version, the space was better used with the previous version

Comment: I for one am not a fan of the redesign. I find myself no longer wanting to review questions and answers as it is. Also, whoever asked for a redesign anyway? There was nothing wrong with the previous version IMHO.

Comment: Whatever happened to **Responsive design**? Responsive design is about using the available space in a matter that makes sense - and half the screen in white does not make sense.

Comment: Adding recent developments together (Job SO closure, + at least two terrible UX "changes"), I think we are now at the point of the end of the Stack Overflow, as we ever knew it. However, SEDE is yet working, and it is yet a perfect tool to measure the evaporation of the users/visitors, to validate or disprove my view.

Comment: "-1 votes" What can I say? Who would ever write that? Does it mean that if there is one more vote we reach no votes at all? I have difficulties imagining how this can have passed quality control.

Comment: @KevinB Exactly. This new design is cleaner in the same way my desk is cleaner when I just shove everything out of the way.

Comment: @Lundin They're planning to make it consistent by making that one look like this one!

Comment: Omg the hideous yellow things are back AGAIN.

Comment: I looked at "top questions" and I have difficulties finding out, what it actually means. There are lots of questions with score 0 and sometimes even -1. Is top questions equal to all questions minus closed/strongly negative questions? Maybe it shouldn't be called "top" then, more like "Acceptable questions". I would have expected really highly scored questions just judging from that title.

Comment: @PoulBak I think "responsive design" has meant here that they make the whole UI again much worser as ever, in exchange they do not improve anything. Normally it means that the CSS is tuned to adapt to various screen widths or mobile/desktop display. Exactly this is what the SO avoids since the very beginning, the so-named "responsiveness" did not change it. Probably no one knows why, their decision makers know it the least.

Comment: Folks, come on! The fact that one can leave a response on the MSE announcement does not make the question off-topic here, I voted to leave it open in review and encourage fellow reviewers to do the same. Where else if not on Meta should we have discussions about merits of UI changes? If anything, as feedback on MSE it would just duplicate already existing feedback.

Comment: @OlegValter It's a cross site duplicate. And the UI change is network wide (or isn't it?). If it's not specific to SO, then this meta is kind of the wrong place to discuss these changes. It won't hurt much but also won't help much. Staff will likely only read there not here.

Comment: @Trilarion it likely is, but I respectfully disagree that this is a closure reason on MSO. I do agree that staff is unlikely to see and/or respond here (unfortunately), but this is beside the point that we *can* have the discussion about the changes here in a community mostly comprised of developers and programmers in a more focused and reasonable way (the irony of saying that isn't lost on me). If we drive off all discussion of changes to MSE, we will eventually lose even more relevance, and I wouldn't want for us to end up mopping up a tumbleweeded site from "I have a  question..." posts...

Comment: @OlegValter true that may be, but almost every concern brought up here has been resolved over there, and responded to by staff, meanwhile over here there's no indication anywhere any of these problems are even being heard.

Comment: @OlegValter I kind of agree that more programmers frequent here than there but wasn't that the deal between MSO and MSE. MSO deals with things relevant to SO only and MSE with everything that affects the whole network. Doesn't that make sense? There is even rep to be gained on MSE.

Comment: No, not necessarily. It follows a relatively similar situation as SO and it's spin off sites do. Just because it's on topic on MSE (or even more applicable), doesn't necessarily mean it's off topic here.

Answer (score 59):

I have a few remarks regarding the details in the left-most column of the list-items.

### The "Watched" marker is too prominent

That marker is big, bold, in full-text and in a yellow frame. That's way too much for something that, in regards to one question, is optional.

Also, it being there or not provides a different layout for the rest of the statistics. The statistics should be at a consistent place from question to question. When the "Watched" marker is absent, everything seems aligned from the top. When the "Watched" marker is present, the whole column on the left seems to be height-centered.

Also, its presence makes questions that can fit on one line take much, much more place, including useless whitespace.

In short, it makes two questions not identical visually, but not by a bit, but by a lot!

A better idea, is that given that "Watched" is linked to tags, put that info in the tags list, just like the collectives.

[image]

### The number of answers

When there is at least one answer, my eye catch the information quite easily. When there are no answers, my eye doesn't see that information until very late. Why? It should be the opposite. If there are no answers, you should try to tell me that I should check that question so that I can check if I should answer it, or handle it in any way SO usually handles questions.

When there are no answer, show it in a similar way than when there is at least one. Not especially in green, if you don't want, but keep the same layout in yellow, in red, whatever.

Comment: Good point on Watched... and I must first question it usefulness. SO is not a news aggregator platforms, I can't find much value in knowing that a question is being "watched". Still if necessary it seems that on the various layouts there's horizontal space on the "tabs" line, so maybe it could be squished in there -- at the beginning of the list?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't question the usefulness of "Watched": I find it very useful as it's questions in a tag I watch. It helps me easily filter questions I can answer when they are asked.

Comment: My mistake, I thought it was a "popularity" indicator -- as in "this question is watched by many people, hot!" -- not something you'd set yourself.

Comment: [Specific link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415540/241211) for "Watched" tags.

Comment: This has been fixed. It's now closer to the old design by just coloring in the background.

Comment: Perhaps your "The number of answers" section should be another answer so that we can upvote that, now that the watched marker issue has been fixed.

Comment: @MegaIng for the time being. They've disabled it and re-enabled colouring while they investigate a bug and other options.

Comment: They seem to have changed it again, so now any tags under the question that are watched get the mustard treatment :-/

Comment: @snakecharmerb yup, there's even more bright yellow than before now. it's like highbeams on the highway, burning away at your retina even when you're not looking at it. (thinking about it, it's just the wrong color for dark theme. it clearly must have a brightness value way beyond anything else on the entire page, except maybe the green for answers but that is used sparingly.)

Answer (score 53):

I've created a userscript called [LegacyQuestions](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacy-questions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design) that brings back the old design.

Here's what it looks like with the userscript:

[image]

Compared to without it:

[image]

Comment: good job, for now it's a good alternative to avoid the headache

Comment: I feel like we're going to have a growing list of userscripts to revert the website back to what it was. This is already #3 on my list. (#1 was the line-height reversion after they changed that. #2 is the removal of collectives userscript).

Comment: just combine them into an extension with a configuration menu

Comment: @ughStackExchange you forgot the font-change userscript :P

Comment: Thanks for the userscript, Spectric (again).  100 reputation says there'll soon be LegacyActive, LegacyUsers, and LegacySE...

Comment: The script was working nicely until an hour or two ago when it suddenly got weird for me. Now it looks like a hybrid of the old design and new design where the metrics appear in a grid like the old design but with the numbers next to the text like the new design. Could just be my browser?

Comment: @Matt This bug has been patched in v1.4. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Whitespace seems to be back on Home > Top questions and Public > Questions.  :-(

Answer (score 16):

I seem to be in the minority, but I personally think the new design is pretty nice. My only issue is that I find it a little confusing having the rep on the left side of the "asked" text.

It manages to read like "1 asked 41 mins ago", possibly because the spacing between the name and the rep is too large and the spacing between the rep and the "asked" text isn't large enough.

This problem would be exaggerated if you're new to the site and aren't familiar with rep.

[image]

Comment: One what? One question asked 41 min ago. As long as the number remains 1, it's probably true. :)

Comment: That is the reputation of the user.

Comment: @Braiam Well _I_ know that, but I'm just pointing out that even though I know it, it's confusing to read, and for people that _don't_ know it it will be especially confusing.

Comment: You may know that, but others may not. I'm commenting for the others benefit.

Answer (score 4):

So now, there's the yellow background *and* yellow watched labels. The labels are just different:

[image: new yellow badges]

Comment: And, what do you think? Better or worse?

Comment: I find it better than the original yellow badges, but worse than just the original yellow background. The new badges are much more informative (I didn't get the meaning of "watched" at first), but they still really stand out and rivet way too much attention.

Comment: it has the same distraction problem as when it was on the left, except it no longer contributes to the height. however, now it can occur multiple times per post and jumps around horizontally from question to question, potentially making it more distracting.

Comment: Maybe inverting the badge, i.e., outlined, would be better, attracting less attention. Kinda like they did to the Staff and Mod labels.

Comment: Looks like Halloween on dark mode :).

Comment: Since tags are all lowercase, could we get a lowercase eyeball to match?

Comment: 1) Yellow background 2) Dark yellow tag 3) Eye icon. Seems like they REALLY want everyone aware of the tags they're watching. Sigh

Comment: The watched tags shouldn't stand out that much. Just a very tiny difference is more than enough. It was fine as it was.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: Don't change the btn color, [change the text color](https://imgur.com/iqAk8PU), if it's neccessary to highlight. Anyway, the update looks much better than it was initial.

Comment: it's way too bright on dark theme

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as Legacy Questions userscript by Spectric, here are Stylus-based user *styles* for reverting the /questions/ list on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow back to the same look and feel as before, since that change recently landed in addition to the Top Questions page:

- Stack Apps link: https://stackapps.com/questions/9324/stack-overflow-questions-design-reversion-to-pre-2022-layout
- GitHub link: https://github.com/Tyler-H/SO-UserScripts/blob/master/Question%20List%20Redesign%20Fix%20(Desktop%20view)
- Just give me the Stylus code:

```css
@-moz-document url("https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions"), url-prefix("https://stackoverflow.com/questions") {
/* Fixing display of stuff on /questions/ pages */

/* restoring font to Arial */
#mainbar, #mainbar a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

/* remove the watched tag styles */
a.post-tag.s-tag__watched, a.post-tag.s-tag__watched:hover {
    background-color: var(--theme-tag-background-color);
    color: var(--theme-tag-color);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .4em .5em;
}
a.post-tag.s-tag__watched::before {
    position: static;
    display: inline;
}

/* restoring the color and display of ignored posts so I don't feel colorblind when using Stack Overflow */
.s-post-summary__ignored .s-post-summary--meta, .s-post-summary__deleted .s-post-summary--meta { 
    filter: grayscale(0%) !important; 
}
.s-post-summary__ignored .s-post-summary--stats-item:not(.is-deleted), 
.s-post-summary__deleted .s-post-summary--stats-item:not(.is-deleted) {
    filter: grayscale(0%) !important;
}
.s-post-summary__ignored .s-post-summary--content-title a.s-link {
    color: var(--theme-question-title-color);
}
.s-post-summary__ignored .s-post-summary--content-title a.s-link:visited {
    color: var(--theme-question-title-color-visited);
}


/* fixing the display of the question entries on the questions pages */
.s-post-summary {
    margin-left: -24px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats {
    margin-right: 16px;
    width: 58px;
}
/* Fixing the 'votes' box */
.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:first-child {
    width: 58px;
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
    color: var(--black-500);
}

.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:first-child span:first-child {
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;    
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:first-child span:last-child {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Fixing the '# of answers' box */
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2) {
    width: 58px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2).has-accepted-answer svg {
    display:none; /* no one needs a checkmark here */
}
.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2) .s-post-summary--stats-item-number {
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2) .s-post-summary--stats-item-unit {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.s-post-summary .js-post-summary-stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

/* fixing the user cards that display at the bottom right */
.s-post-summary .s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal {
    display: grid;
    width: 185px;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card time {
    display: flex;
    order: 1;
    height: 18px;
    align-items: center;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card time span.relativetime {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card a {
    display: block;
    order: 2;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card a.s-avatar {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card a div img.s-avatar--image {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card div.s-user-card--info {
    display: block;
    order: 3;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    height: 32px;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card div.s-user-card--info ul.s-user-card--awards { 
    height: 17px;    
}

/* fixing the user cards that display at the bottom right */
.s-post-summary .s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal {
    display: grid;
    width: 185px;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card time {
    display: flex;
    order: 1;
    height: 18px;
    align-items: center;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card time span.relativetime {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card a {
    display: block;
    order: 2;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card a.s-avatar {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card a div img.s-avatar--image {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card div.s-user-card--info {
    display: block;
    order: 3;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    height: 32px;
}
.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--meta .s-user-card div.s-user-card--info ul.s-user-card--awards { 
    height: 17px;    
}
}
```