# I hate these new yellow 'watch' labels

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

These new yellow 'Watched' labels - I assume that they mean 'These items contain tags that are a part of your watch list'.

[image]

It's less jarring in light-theme, but still unpleasant:

[image]

They're way too intrusive, they look like 'this is important' or 'action required' - and almost every item on my feed has them.

The old system of dulling out the non-watched labels was a lot more subtle and easy on the eye.

Comment: Already reported on MSE: [here in the comments](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479/289905), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375501/289905), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375508/289905), and [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375512/289905).

Comment: Already reported, sure, but still hard to understand why anyone thought this was okay. Did they do *any*user testing? If feels like the most insignificant thing is yelling at us.

Comment: "*The old system of dulling out the non-watched labels*" That wasn't the old system. The old system put a yellow background on questions with watched tags. Darkening out questions only happened for tags on your ignore list, and only on lists not on the main page.

Comment: @Mark: "*Did they do anyuser testing?*" It's entirely possible that the answer is "no". It appears likely that the initial feature didn't have any highlighting for questions from watched tags. When they released it on the main page for every site, people pointed out that the watched indicator went away. So then we got this big box. It's possible that they just threw together a quickie indicator without thinking about usability at all.

Comment: If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it...

Comment: @Mark "*Did they do anyuser testing?*" sure - when they pushed it to develop, now all users are testing it. Wouldn't be the first time that happened.

Comment: Made a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375520/353058) for restoring the background.

Comment: Oh man, that adds even more unused whitespace, having those labels push everything down...

Comment: Try finding a question with five tags, it pushes the name of the author down making everything look lopsided. Ugh. I have so many questions about this but I can summarise them with only one question: "Why?". The existing design was eye pleasing, color coordinated, authorised. And now... it's the exact opposite.

Comment: A large number of people like a site's style enough to frequent the site (making it familiar and comfortable); then the site decides to "update" the site's style. The end result is that a large number of people hate the new style (regardless of whether it's better or worse) because it's not what they liked about the site originally and the site suddenly became unfamiliar. The fact that it violates "separation of form and content", which is one of the very first things any beginner learns (as it allows browser to do the right thing) and causes 20% of a wide screen to be wasted doesn't help.

Comment: @Mark This is the user testing :p

Comment: If I were conspiratorially minded, I'd say the point of the yellow watch labels is to have an obvious, easy-fixable flaw for people to complain about. Once they fix it, the other aspects of the redesign will look acceptable by comparison.

Comment: Came here to check what's whrong with my browser. There's now a yellow hightlight of totally useless information presented more promenently than the important label. Maybe I'll get used to it, but at the moment my reaction is to stop browsing stack overflow for my subscribed tags...

Comment: Wow! Opening SO this morning and... no longer any overview. OK, maybe because its simply new. But where are the votes gone. It was very helpful that a question already has a lot of downvotes to ignore them and find useful ones by high votes. Not longer possible... Thanks! It simply makes no fun anymore to visit the site time by time. I leave SO for now... maybe asking questions maybe, but I believe the user frequence will decrease so much that it will not as helpful as before... back to newsgroups... who has done that change? And why??????

Comment: BTW: I read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el and my first hope was to simply downvote. But thats needs a new registration and 100 votes myself. In fact, I can't downvote. It is a very good strategy to close the eyes and ears simply by building a wall against feedback :-) Congratulations. I SIMPLY WANT BACK THE YESTERDAY STYLE!

Comment: **＊pitchfork raised＊** Until the designer is reprimanded, forced to change it, and been made to reflect on their crime against humanity... we can use the browser add-on [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) to override the site's CSS. Target `stackoverflow.com` and add this CSS: `.s-post-summary__watched .is-watched {background-color: transparent; color: rgba(206, 168, 29, 0.42)}` (By the way, if the color has gotten you like, viscerally upset... it may be a sign that you're spending way too many hours of your life on SE. Maybe go outside and get some fresh air. )

Comment: I remember seeing the meta question a week ago, but people only complain now... maybe that counts as user testing. (on the other hand there was *some* early feedback, although definitely not *that* badly-received)

Comment: @Mentalist why has your comment suddenly made me envision the Monty Python "We apologise again for the fault in the subtitles. The people responsible for sacking the previous people have now been sacked.".... Truth be told I usually have a screen on SO when I'm at work so that I can just answer a question or two when I have brainfade - I find the distraction of SO freshens my mind a bit.

Comment: Did they even *tell* anyone they intended to roll this out?

Comment: Best part is that when you filter the questions, it still has the old style.

Comment: In the dark theme they are so big, bright, and out of place that I can't even read a question title without my eye jumping back to these labels on every line. ugh.

Comment: I was so confused as to what this was because I come to SO via a bookmark that takes me directly to a custom filter that doesn't have these yellow boxes. So I had to go hunting! They are a very "in your face" with the dark theme though.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/268911). And only on MSE.

Comment: At first I thought "oh, they are now reporting changes in the questions I watch". Next thought "Why are so many questions I watch changing?". Third thought "Why am I watching this question?". Finally I understood that "watched" on SO means something different that "watching a Github repo". It's annoying and a waste of time.

Comment: In terms of UX design it looks like it's a warning there !

Comment: [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) @KarlKnechtel though it wasn't in the side bar until recently

Comment: the question is, why? now my eyes go too much towards those yellow labels

Comment: "User testing was run with ~170 recently active users" Are you serious??

Comment: Less intrusive solution might be to slightly emphasize tags on the question that are being watched.

Comment: @ChristianP Or, just color the background of the box.

Comment: (1) Go to your profile, (2) Click "Edit Profile", (3) Click "Tag watching & ignoring", (4) Click the little "X" next to each tag. **I'm not saying this to be snarky** - it's just not that obvious how to remove a watched tag since I've never had a reason to try before now, and this actually solves the problem for me. I can still filter questions by tag if I choose and the terrible new layout becomes 1% less terrible.

Comment: @billynoah you could also just click "Edit" in the watched tags box and then click the X's

Comment: Watched tags box being on the right sidebar on the homepage.  It was also the very first thing I did on seeing this...

Comment: I hope that this is a kind of canary release and that it will be removed because it's really not relevant

Comment: Okay, stop! Just stop! The site was fine the way it was! Why make all these changes? First, we had to put up with a new "responsive" design. Next, they're telling us that the Jobs and the Dev Story are leaving. Now, we have construction-area-yellow labels for watched tags along with a bunch of wasteful whitespace. The [tour] says that SO is _"...built and run by you..."_; I _beg_ to differ. Not only did I not authorize any of this, but apparently my complaints are just getting turned the deaf ear of a big corporation. Hopefully _someone_ sees this the way I do?

Comment: The article states were introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/794), more were added with [this one](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/806) and got refined with [20 days ago](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/819).

Comment: “But the plans were on display…”
“On display? I eventually had to go down to the cellar to find them.”
“That’s the display department.”
“With a flashlight.”
“Ah, well, the lights had probably gone.”
“So had the stairs.”
“But look, you found the notice, didn’t you?”
“Yes,” said Arthur, “yes I did. It was on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard.” - Douglas Adams, The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Comment: Mission accomplished, watched label removed and the old highlighting is back. Now if they would just undo all the other changes...

Comment: @Boann if only Dilbert worked at SO: https://dilbert.com/strip/2007-02-02

Comment: It's... better. But the new design proves one thing: *more horizontal space needed*.

Comment: @j08691 All the way back to 2018.

Comment: Someone must be *really* fond of their *yellow watch badges*. The yellow badge has now moved to the tags section, where it is just as much of eyesore as it was on the left.

Answer (score 44):

I'd like to give [a suggestion by deceze](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375512#comment1250980_375512) more attention.

> Suggestion: why not highlight the tags themselves instead of adding an additional tag?

and further [comment by simonalexander2005](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375512#comment1251031_375512)

> Highlighting just the individual tag would also quickly remind you which tag you're watching for this question

Comment: An interesting idea, but I'd do it **in addition** to background highlight.

Comment: "Highlighting just the individual tag" Agreed. - If you watch "javascript", "typescript", and "C#" about 90% of the home page is "watched", making the current label useless. Highlighting the individual tag would at least show you why something is watched.

Comment: they seem to have highlighted the tags themselves now, but it's still way too bright on dark theme

Answer (score 11):

I, too, would like to see this removed. I can read the tags (and question title) on my own just fine; I don't need to see a label prominently mentioning that I'm watching the tags - it makes no difference in how likely I am to read the question and it's just distracting.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to have been fixed (for now, at least). On [the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/), the yellow "Watched" label is no longer showing for questions where one of more of the tags are in your watched list. [This MSE complaint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375508) has been marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Also see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375508#comment1251289_375508).

Answer (score 6):

What are "watches" anyway? We can watch tags and we used to be able to watch posts (or was it favourite?). Nowadays we *bookmark* posts, after some other recent UI change. When we click on bookmark next to a post it turns yellow/orange. After which we can find it from our user profile -> bookmarks.

So "watched" means... what?

- A tag I'm watching?
- A question watched by someone currently, as in currently viewed?
- A question bookmarked by me?
- A question bookmarked by someone else? (Why should I care?)

Questions to the UI designers:

- Why the inconsistent terms "watch" vs "bookmark"?
- Why is the top question page terms and layout inconsistent with https://stackoverflow.com/questions?
- Why are both of the above inconsistent with the layout when opening a specific question? There's this little strange banner with a star there and it shows how many that <strike>watch</strike> bookmarked it.
- Why isn't saying "watched" in the specific question? If I mouse-over the banner thing it says "bookmark this question" or "you have bookmarked this question".

Comment: The "watched" label means the question has a watched tag; see also the "watched tags" box on the sidebar when opening SO.com. Every question that had a yellow background in the old design now has the "watched" label. It has nothing to do with bookmarks (or follows, which is yet another thing you can do with posts) and I'm unsure why you would think it has someting to do with other users. That part is IMO actually consistent. Doesn't change the fact that the redesign is garbage and should be reverted ASAP though...

Comment: @l4mpi That's about the last thing I'd think it means. Congratulations to SO for lowering the bar on terrible UX.

Comment: A side note: we can still "watch" posts by clicking the "follow" button.

Comment: _“Why is the top question page terms and layout inconsistent with https://stackoverflow.com/questions?”_ — Because `/questions` hasn’t been converted to the new layout yet.

Answer (score 4):

Oh my god, I thought yellow label "Watched" meant "someone is reading this post right now", like they do on the booking websites:

[image]

Comment: It is indeed very ambiguous and misleading. I've been using Watched Tags for years and when I first saw the yellow label this morning, I thought it meant "You've already viewed this question" and was like "No, I didn't!" - until I finally realized what it meant.

Answer (score 3):

I'm watching the `regex` tag and if I filter to just Python (non-watched) then it uses the old highlighting.

This isn't so much an answer as it is an observation.

I agree though, the yellow "Watched" label is really an eyesore.

[image]

Comment: That's because not all lists have the new layout but they will eventually

Comment: @charlietfl I am aware of that but based on this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375478/235923) it looks like this list already skipped a generation of changes?

Comment: I always just use a custom search (on a bunch of tags) to find activity in tags I'm interested in.  The custom filter seems designed for that.  I never noticed the existence of this mis-feature, although possibly it also came and went while I was asleep.

Answer (score 2):

Where was user feedback and testing? I remember there used to be meta threads where users will be asked for feedback on some new features. Like reducing from 5 votes to 3 votes for closing a question.

Now all of a sudden some new feature is released, without any feedback.

Comment: Well, that's not _exactly_ true. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) existed for two weeks before the change was actually implemented, and people thought they would like it, based on limited demo imagery...but still, it wasn't really soliciting user approbation, but rather announcing a planned change.

Comment: tbh, i've given up giving feedback on such posts, not because i don't think it'd help, but because it's always felt like a waste of time. Until it actually launches, we can't know whether or not the feedback we provide is actually shared among any sort of majority of users.

Comment: It's also kinda difficult to know how something will affect your workflow... without it being in your workflow.

Comment: "but still, it wasn't really soliciting user approbation, but rather announcing a planned change." yes, "announcing" in a place where the audience is... I guess probably more than the 170 people they tested with, but *still a tiny fraction of users*, realistically speaking.

Answer (score -3):

**Remove all your watched tags.** That'll teach 'em. Or probably not, but at this point, who really cares?

[image]

Ahhhh... much better.

Comment: You can also hide the watched tag with a content blocker like ublock origin.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili This is easier.

Comment: Sure, but doing it my way you can hide a ton of useless stuff from the home page, like the collectives and blog posts.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili True, but doing it my way actively causes harm to SO's ability to collect and analyze data. Maybe I'll do both.

Comment: *"who really cares"* .. I do! I expect similar highlighting to the old version to be implemented again. Why should users have to sacrifice convenience due to poor design decisions?