# Redundant Highlighting of Posts and Tags With Watched Tags

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

Similar to this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415552/10746872) posted 2 days ago regarding the word "Watched" being highlighted unnecessarily, the new design introduced today has the same effect of drawing user's attention away from the important information of a post, the title.

[image: Stack Overflow Highlighted Watched Tags]

The post already has a highlighted background and I really don't need to be reminded which tags I am already watching. This change seems redundant and overall pulls away from concentrating on the posts.

Comment: I actually prefer to know which of the tags I followed are on a post *(as I follow many tags, and often forget which ones)*.

Comment: @AnnZen I understand your point, so maybe a less-jarring approach could be taken because bright bold yellow is not appealing. And/or a toggle for tag highlights for users who don't want to see this.

Comment: It's still the new watched sign you dislike; even if it's the "new new" watched sign, as the initial one was so poorly received.

Comment: Courtesy of the Department of Redundancy Department

Comment: @VoidTwo That sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: I don't mind calling attention to which tags are followed. However, I wish it wasn't so prominent. Those tags are the heaviest element on the page, but not remotely the most important thing to see when scanning.

Comment: The color is so annoying as well.

Comment: As to "why the yellow" - likely because it's tradition. When you followed a post, we added a slightly yellow cast to the post background. With a brighter yellow like this, though, particularly for dark mode, it might be reasonable to question whether this is the "right" color choice. That said, I do like the tags having something special going on. We also have to be cautious because tags come in all colors network-wide... but not this color yellow. Less visible colors might end up being indistinguishable from a per-site tag color. :) Worth looking into, though.

Comment: Worth noting that this has been reported on the Meta.SE thread [in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375637) [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375638) [places](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375639) too, with [[tag:status-review]] tags to boot.

Comment: @Catija how about only adding the eye thingy and leaving everything else equal.

Comment: @Samathingamajig You are the 2nd or 3rd person to recommend this post as a duplicate, but I already mentioned this in my very first sentence and if you look closely, these are 2 completely different elements of the UI. My post is solely based on the highlighting of tags whereas the post you have linked focused on the "Watched" label which has already been reverted.